# Apache POI unable to open embedded files

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to embed a PDF file in an excel, I am able to embed the file but it is not opening. Excel is showing the image I had anchored to, but on click of it, nothing happens as it is just an image.

```java
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("dr.xlsx"));
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("test.pdf");
FileInputStream fs1 = new FileInputStream("download.png");
int pdf = wb.addOlePackage(IOUtils.toByteArray(fs), "text.pdf", "text.pdf", "text.pdf");
int anc = wb.addPicture(IOUtils.toByteArray(fs1), HSSFPicture.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
XSSFDrawing draw = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
ClientAnchor anchor = draw.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 4);
anchor.setAnchorType(ClientAnchor.AnchorType.DONT_MOVE_AND_RESIZE);
XSSFObjectData objectData = draw.createObjectData(anchor, pdf, anc);
objectData.getCTShape().getNvSpPr().getCNvPr().setName( "text.pdf");
objectData.getCTShape().getNvSpPr().getCNvPr().setHidden(false);
```

[image: Spreadsheet showing icon of PDF]

Comment: [XSSFObjectData](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_1_2/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFObjectData.java?view=markup) uses `XML` elements from namespace `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main"`. So this only can work using `Excel` version 2010 or later. And this is not the way `Excel` itself embeds object data. `Excel` itself uses `VMLDrawing` instead a default `Drawing` for this. But `apache poi` has only very limited support for `VMLDrawing`.

Comment: if you create a workbook from scratch (instead of using the dr.xlsx) it works with your code and Office 2016 - Libre Office can't open it anyway. I'm having a look now, what's different when using an arbitrary file ...

Comment: @anshul-kumar:  I had some problems with that test-case, as my main office installation crashed with some [grooveex.dll](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_onedrivefb-mso_win10/what-does-grooveexdll-do-exactly/36f971c1-69c1-4270-a1c9-685178b9e02b), but two other Office installations (2016 / 365) opened the file just fine - so please check also for grooveex.dll which was installed through a OneNote update.
I'll commit [a few minor changes](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64512) soon, you might want to try a nightly build then ...